Why my Ubuntu apps, icons, terminal , setting these are not opened after update and upgrade ubuntu?
Recently I update my ubuntu to latest version and upgrade but after that my systems's all icons of apps not showing only showing their names. Setting, Terminal, and almost all apps not open by clicking. Only I chrome and vscode open. Why this happend ? Any troubleshoot in my system or any broken. Please help

You've tagged your question as being about Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (or the 2020-April release), but also mention the latest version which is four years & eight releases later than what you tagged; so please clarify your details.  What OS/release are you using? and what exactly do you mean by update?
